# Finding possibly matching strings in a large dataset

Tags: hashmap, string-comparison, wikipedia, n-gram, large-data

I'm in the middle of a project where I have to process text documents and enhance them with Wikipedia links. Preprocessing a document includes locating all the possible target articles, so I extract all ngrams and do a comparison against a database containing all the article names. The current algorithm is a simple caseless string comparison preceded by simple trimming. However, I'd like it to be more flexible and tolerant to errors or little text modifications like prefixes etc. Besides, the database is pretty huge and I have a feeling that string comparison in such a large database is not the best idea...

What I thought of is a hashing function, which would **assign a unique** (I'd rather avoid collisions) **hash to any article or ngram so that I could compare hashes instead of the strings**. The difference between two hashes would let me know if the words are similiar so that I could gather all the possible target articles.

Theoretically, I could use cosine similiarity to calculate the similiarity between words, but this doesn't seem right for me because comparing the characters multiple times sounds like a performance issue to me.

Is there any recommended way to do it? Is it a good idea at all? **Maybe the string comparison with proper indexing isn't that bad and the hashing won't help me here**?

I looked around the hashing functions, text similarity algoriths, but I haven't found a solution yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [Apache Lucene API](https://lucene.apache.org) It provides functionality for searching, stemming, tokenization, indexing, document similarity scoring. Its an open source implementation of basic best practices in Information Retrieval

The functionality that seems most useful to you from Lucene is their *moreLikeThis* algorithm which uses Latent Semantic Analysis to locate similar documents.

Comment: I'll give Lucene a chance if I don't find any other solution, but I'd rather do my own - even a very naive - implementation than use an additional library.

Comment: @MaciejNaruszewicz Did you do your own implementation? Can you share your algorithm for the same?

Comment: @ShwetabhShekhar I used direct string comparison but if I were to improve the project today, I would definitely use Apache Lucene